# Is it possible to access a mongo database cluster from a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, fetch-api, mongodb-atlas

I am writing a little chrome extension for personal use, and I'm trying to connect it to a mongo database that is used by a website I've built using meteor. I've seen how a chrome extension can make a web request, but near as I can tell, it exclusively uses HTTP, which is blocked by mongoDB Atlas. So, I'm wondering:

1. Is there a way to do a HTTPS request from a chrome extension
2. Is there a way to access MongoDB Atlas over HTTP
3. Am I missing an alternative somewhere?

Comment: Extensions aren't limited to http. If you encounter problems, add [MCVE](/help/mcve) to the question. Off the top of my head you didn't add the necessary host permissions in manifest.json or the request is in a content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm, How would I go about doing https then? According to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
I'm not seeing anything about https

Comment: There's nothing to see, nothing to do specifically, it just works. If it doesn't for you, please show an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

1. The sample uses https to access GAS.
2. I think it is impossible because Javascript does not provide an API for converting mongodb+srv to https.
3. Consider using Java, Node.js, Python, etc.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "GAS",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://script.google.com/"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

myscript.js

```js
document.getElementById("exec").onclick = () => {
  const from_lang = "ja";
  const from_text = "こんにちは、世界。";
  const to_lang = "en";
  let url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzJSwh2FK-3oj5yojegIaC2ny8dPWZwaF_JqMT5vysvAo1jRyZ_3juOmCa0VErfsa84TA/exec";
  url += "?text=" + from_text + "&source=" + from_lang + "&target=" + to_lang;
  fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors"
  })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.text();
      }
      throw new Error("Response was not ok.");
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
}
```

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="exec" value="exec">
  <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```